# jQuery-jScrollPane incorrect width

Tags: jquery, initialization, width, jscrollpane

I have a scrollable container, which contains table with unknow number of rows. I`m generating whole html from script.

This is the order of view creation :

1. Create container without content
2. Get data from cache, and create table
3. Append chosen table to scrollable container
4. Initialise jScrollPane

The result is jspContainer with width and height set to 0.

I suspect that reason is that table isn't fully (dom tree isn't ready) ready while I`m initialising jScrollPane.
For now I sorted this out by runing initialise is timeOut set to 0, but I want to get rid of timeOut.

Any ideas how to fix that? For now I tried the fallowing :

1. Initialise jScrollPane before creating table, after appending table to view - call reinitialise
2. Initialise jScrollPane with contentWidth set to width of table
3. Set inline style width of container element to width of table

The whole thing is complex so I will add some pseudocode.

```
function createWidget(opts){
     createView();
     addFunctionality();
}

function createView(){
     //set innerHTML of view here
     //and create references to interactive elements
}

function addFunctionality(){
     //create event delegat for interactive elements
     createRest();
     $( elements[customScr] ).jScrollPane().removeAttr(ti);    
     //elements is a map with references to important elements
}

function createRest(){
     //get data from cache

     //create appropriate amount of tables
     //and fill it with rows - all is based on cache data

     //append 1st table to view
     $( elements[customScr] ).data("jsp").reinitialise();
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code, consider make a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Whole widget is kind of complex. You can change the content of each tab, and everything is updated based on live data, so I don't want to waste time to prepare jsfiddle. I provided pseudocode, I hope it is enough.

Comment: You should call jScrollPane(); before createRest and reinitialise when table are fully populated

Comment: As I mentioned above, I also tried that, no effect.

"Any ideas how to fix that? For now I tried the fallowing :

Initialise jScrollPane before creating table, after appending table to view - call reinitialise"

Comment: That should be the way to go, is it possible that the CSS is making the table or the wrapping container height to be set to 0 due to float or similar rule?

Comment: The table wrapper has set height, and the table has set width. I was trying to force the proper size on both of them, but it had no effect on jScrollPane